# Is there a method to retrieve all tracks from a playlist using Spotipy?

Tags: python, spotipy

I'm trying to extract all songs from one of my playlists in Spotify. Using the spotipy package in Python to help accomplish this. Below is the current code I have, which only gets 100 tracks. I tried poking around the internet for solutions but nothing appeared to work. Below is the code that I have so far.

```
#Import Library
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import spotipy
from matplotlib import style
from spotipy import util
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials 

#Set up Connection 
client_id = 'id' #Need to create developer profile
client_secret = 'secret'
username = 'username' #Store username
scope = 'user-library-read playlist-modify-public playlist-read-private'
redirect_uri='uri'
client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=client_id, 
client_secret=client_secret)#Create manager for ease
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, client_id, 
client_secret, redirect_uri)

if token:
 sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
else:
 print("Can't get token for", username)

#Connect to the best playlist, like ever 
playlist_id = 'playlist'
playlist = sp.user_playlist(username,playlist_id)

#Extract list of songs/tracks
tracks = playlist["tracks"];
songs = tracks["items"];

track_ids = []
track_names = []

for i in range(0, len(songs)):
 if songs[i]['track']['id'] != None: # Removes  local tracks, if any
    track_ids.append(songs[i]['track']['id'])
    track_names.append(songs[i]['track']['name'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use offset to collect the results from multiple calls. This function returns a list of track objects.

```
def user_playlist_tracks_full(spotify_connection, user, playlist_id=None, fields=None, market=None):
    """ Get full details of the tracks of a playlist owned by a user.
        https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/get-playlists-tracks/

        Parameters:
            - user - the id of the user
            - playlist_id - the id of the playlist
            - fields - which fields to return
            - market - an ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code.
    """

    # first run through also retrieves total no of songs in library
    response = spotify_connection.user_playlist_tracks(user, playlist_id, fields=fields, limit=100, market=market)
    results = response["items"]

    # subsequently runs until it hits the user-defined limit or has read all songs in the library
    while len(results) < response["total"]:
        response = spotify_connection.user_playlist_tracks(
            user, playlist_id, fields=fields, limit=100, offset=len(results), market=market
        )
        results.extend(response["items"])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! Pretty new to the package, and the documentation of Spotipy's own site isn't the most clear- could you clarify what the "fields" component of the function represents?

Comment: Sure! It can limit the data that gets returned, e.g. `fields="total,limit"` - more details on [the API reference for `user_playlist_tracks`](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/get-playlists-tracks/)